# Testing iOS B2B Store App in development without submitting it to Apple

Tags: ios, testing, configuration, environment, b2b

I am writing an app which will be deployed on the Apple B2B store.

I was wondering how to go about testing this in development before going through the Apple review process.

The main thing I want to test is providing configuration through the managed configuration capability from an MDM (via com.apple.configuration.managed file which is pushed from MDM)

Here's a couple of links explaining the process and handling of it.

[Example of handling this in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/sc2279/Introduction/Intro.html)

[Article on the feature](http://tomasmcguinness.com/2014/01/23/ios-managed-app-configuration/)

Although the article talks about Enterprise apps, B2B apps can also be managed.

So can I test this before sending it to apple for approval. What are my options? Is it possible with test flight?

Comment: have you found a solution? We just decided this is the best choice for distributing a few of ours apps, but we want to test before then!

Comment: No, unfortunately not yet